# WWW version as website binding or a DNS record?

Tags: dns-zone, windows-server-2019, bindings

In a **windows server** I am trying to setup a new domain and run a website. Which method should I use to access the website using **www.** prefix?

1. using IIS by adding a website binding with **www.** prefix to the website settings? It seems this method has nothing to do with DNS records.
2. or adding **A record** in dns manager with the name **www**?

(or both are needed?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the site via [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) then you need a DNS record for www, or a wildcard DNS record.

Adding the binding to IIS is optional. If this is the only website in IIS then all requests will go to this website, regardless of the name the user types in the browser.

[www.example.com](http://www.example.com), mysite.example.com, blahblahblah.example.com, etc., etc.